# googlemaps error log:api key not found

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

i created android key.
i use the key in my code

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.androoid.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyDlSZf-YTqh_rBLyzjzB6VanBVm4xk6VvI"/>
```

but android can't found api key.
i don't know this error cause.

> 01-15 15:12:33.526: E/AndroidRuntime(28834): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

**mannifest file**
    '

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission 
       android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<!--
The following two permissions are not required to use
Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlemap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <meta-data android:value="4030500" 
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.androoid.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="AIzaSyDlSZf-YTqh_rBLyzjzB6VanBVm4xk6VvI"/>

</application>

</manifest>
'
```

Comment: that meta tag should be in the applicaion tag of manifest. post the manifest file

Comment: adjust my post. i added manifest file.

Comment: try generating a new key or try clean and build. Also remove the first meta tag

Comment: does the suggestion in my post fix your problem??

Comment: @user3196546 +1 for you:) dude.welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use these line

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="AIzaSyDlSZf-YTqh_rBLyzjzB6VanBVm4xk6VvI"/>
```

instead of

```
<meta-data android:value="4030500" 
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.androoid.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="AIzaSyDlSZf-YTqh_rBLyzjzB6VanBVm4xk6VvI"/>
```

Comment: if it is than please accept the answer and raise it that it will be useful for oters

Comment: so vote should be for you only...+1 from my side to you!! you well deserves!!

Comment: @user3196546 hey please accept the answer of Raghunandan only when you will have enough points to do that!!

Answer (score 4):

Change this

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.androoid.maps.v2.API_KEY"   
          android:value="AIzaSyDlSZf-YTqh_rBLyzjzB6VanBVm4xk6VvI"/>
 // androoid should be android
```

to

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="AIzaSyDlSZf-YTqh_rBLyzjzB6VanBVm4xk6VvI"/>
```

and remove

```
<meta-data android:value="4030500" 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"/>
```

Also clean and build the project. If it does not work try regenerating the api key again

Comment: i gave +1 to you @Raghunandan you deserves :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers already given, I had a similar version of this problem and found a solution as follows.

I noticed that for some reason my `google_maps_api.xml` file in the values folder had been renamed `google_maps_api.xml (w820dp)`. It appeared that in trying to rename the file it still appended the `w820dp`. I made a note of my api key and deleted the file entirely, adding a new version, which wasn't appended with `w820dp`. This fixed the problem.

Comment: This happened because you probably copied google_maps_api.xml file from your other app that uses the maps api key.